# zathura config keybinding not working as supposed to in the documentation?

Tags: configuration, pdf, zathura

According to the man-page, it's possible to rebind keys in zathura, but I can't seem to get it to work.

N is "search next" and n is "search previous". I would like it to be the other way around. However, when adding this my  file, looking at the [documentation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-zathurarc/) :

```
unmap n
unmap N
map N search previous
map n search next
```

But now both n and N searches forward instead.

I've tried experimenting with the argument up, down, right and left, that is supplied in the documentation, but they don't do anything. In fact, I suspect that it does not recognize the argument "previous" at all, but defaults to the default search argument, which is probably "next".

I also tried  --previous and -previous, just because, but of course that didn't work either.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm on a lubuntu 20.04 machine, with

```
zathura 0.4.5
girara 0.3.4 (runtime: 0.3.4)
(plugin) pdf-poppler (0.3.0) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zathura/libpdf-poppler.so)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey not sure if it still matters but you just forgot to add `[normal]` after the map. I have this in my config and it works:

```
map [normal] n search forward
map [normal] p search backward
```

Now to unbind \ as search and replace it is something I am still trying to figure out.